# Difference between bulb sockets

Tags: opel, dashboard, astra, bulbs

What is the difference between the following bulb sockets: `b8.5d`, `b8.4d` and `bx8.4d`? **Are they interchangeable?** (And especially, what's the difference with the `x` and non-`x` version?)

Background: I need to replace the lighting on the dashboard (Opel Astra G, in case that matters), and various sources provide different light bulb types (and I did not find much about the topic, after repeated searches).

Comment: Which year of Opel Astra G?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2: 1999

Answer (score 4):

You can see the different shapes and dimensions of the bulb holders in these images that I collected from the [Ring](https://www.ringautomotive.com/en/product/R509TVI) website.  Probably best just pick the one that looks the same and has the same dimensions as the ones you have.

Ignore the weight and wattage, just focus on the base and dimensions.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]